# Custom View animation is smoother than Custom SurfaceView animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I have develop similar implementation to test if I should go for View or SurfaceView. I implemented the View as below

```
public class TimerView extends View {

    private Paint mPiePaint;
    private RectF mShadowBounds;
    private float diameter;

    int startCount = 0;
    private PanelThread thread;

    public TimerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPiePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPiePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPiePaint.setColor(0xff000000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // Account for padding
        float xpad = (float)(getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
        float ypad = (float)(getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

        float ww = (float)w - xpad;
        float hh = (float)h - ypad;

        // Figure out how big we can make the pie.
        diameter = Math.min(ww, hh);
        mShadowBounds = new RectF(0, 0, diameter, diameter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (startCount == 360) startCount= 0;
        canvas.drawArc(mShadowBounds,
                0, startCount, true, mPiePaint);
        invalidate();
        startCount++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
        int w = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
        int h = resolveSizeAndState(MeasureSpec.getSize(w), heightMeasureSpec, 0);
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

}
```

And I implemented my Surface View as below

```
public class TimerSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Paint mPiePaint;
    private RectF mShadowBounds;
    private float diameter;

    int startCount = 0;
    private PanelThread thread;

    public TimerSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TimerSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TimerSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TimerSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mPiePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPiePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPiePaint.setColor(0xff000000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // Account for padding
        float xpad = (float)(getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
        float ypad = (float)(getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

        float ww = (float)w - xpad;
        float hh = (float)h - ypad;

        // Figure out how big we can make the pie.
        diameter = Math.min(ww, hh);
        mShadowBounds = new RectF(0, 0, diameter, diameter);

    }

    protected void drawSomething(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFEEEEEE);

        if (startCount == 360) startCount= 0;
        canvas.drawArc(mShadowBounds,
                0, startCount, true, mPiePaint);
        startCount++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
        int w = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
        int h = resolveSizeAndState(MeasureSpec.getSize(w), heightMeasureSpec, 0);
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()
        thread = new PanelThread(getHolder(), this); //Start the thread that
        thread.setRunning(true);                     //will make calls to
        thread.start();                              //onDraw()
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
        // this is a clean shutdown
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And SurfaceView Thread as below

```
class PanelThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private TimerSurfaceView panel;
    private boolean starRunning = false;


    public PanelThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, TimerSurfaceView panel) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.panel = panel;
    }


    public void setRunning(boolean run) { //Allow us to stop the thread
        starRunning = run;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (starRunning) {     //When setRunning(false) occurs, starRunning is
            c = null;      //set to false and loop ends, stopping thread
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    //Insert methods to modify positions of items in onDraw()
                    panel.drawSomething(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result shows that Custom View (TimerView) is smoother than the Surface View, as show in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9craUgY3I4 . According to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893266/why-surfaceview-is-slower-than-a-custom-view`, the SurfaceView though slower, should be smoother.

Could it because in SurfaceView, I need to recolor to erase the previous draw `canvas.drawColor(0xFFEEEEEE);` on `drawSomething` function? Is there a way to eliminate the need of recoloring, like what I did in TimerView, I just `invalidate()` it during `onDraw`?

The other issue I face is, when the App go the background and return, the `drawSomthing` of TimerSurfaceView will receive a null Canvas, while the TimerView onDraw() doesn't invalidate, and animation just stop. Is there anything I need to do to let it continue where it was?

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in an answer-comment on the question you linked to:

> Canvas rendering to a SurfaceView is not hardware-accelerated, while Canvas rendering to a plain View is.

As the display pixel counts get higher (due to the inevitable drive for 4K displays on tiny devices), software rendering becomes slower.  Increases in CPU performance and memory bandwidth will offset this, but it's just not going to perform well on some devices.

You can compensate for this in various ways, e.g. [using `setFixedSize()` to limit the pixel count](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html), but hardware-accelerated rendering is generally a better approach.

If your frame rate is being limited by the CPU, then anything that wants to use the same CPU core is going to cause jank.  The fact that you can put the SurfaceView renderer on a separate thread is helpful, but if you're pushing the device's limits then it just won't matter.  The display is updating at a certain rate, and if you don't meet the deadline consistently then your animation will not be smooth.  (Some additional thoughts can be found in [this appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops).)

Comment: Ya, I'm aware that Surface view is slower. My inquiry is why my SurfaceView is not as smooth as View onDraw... I though the main reason one is using SufaceView is because it could thread it's operation to another process, and hence making it smoother animating than View.

Comment: Again, if you miss the display refresh deadline, you're going to have jank. You've got 16.7ms to render each frame at 60fps, and software rendering on larger displays is going to have trouble keeping up. Take it to the extreme: if software rendering to a SurfaceView takes 200ms (5fps), it will not look smoother than hardware rendering to a custom View that only takes 10ms per frame. Multi-threading is not a silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Android devs said you should do all animations on the main thread, since their framework doesn't work so well otherwise with UI work

Comment: What do you mean with Android devs ? You should add your source.